# JSON result into a pretty HTML table

Tags: php, json, httprequest

I have fetched some data through a JSON url request, but it's not very presentable. Example:

> {\"Candidates\":{\"row\":{\"no\":\"1\",\"FL\":[{\"content\":\"213748000001280336\",\"val\":\"RESUMEID\"},{\"content\":\"Torsten M (001)\",\"val\":\"Modified by\"},{\"content\":\"Today\",\"val\":\"Modified time\"},{\"content\":\"3317\",\"val\":\"Candidate ID\"},{\"content\":\"Peter\",\"val\":\"Fornavn / First name\"},{\"content\":\"L\",\"val\":\"Efternavn / Surname\"},{\"content\":\"Københavnsområdet,Region Sjælland\",\"val\":\"Hvilken eller hvilke regioner ønsker du arbejde i? / Please select regions where you would like to work\"},{\"content\":\"peterl@hotmail.com\",\"val\":\"E-mail\"},{\"content\":\"12345678\",\"val\":\"Telefon / Phone\"},{\"content\":\"Today\",\"val\":\"Oprettelsesdato\"},{\"content\":\"0-25.000\",\"val\":\"Lønniveau\"},{\"content\":\"Internal\",\"val\":\"Kilde\"},{\"content\":\"Torsten M (001)\",\"val\":\"Rekrutteringsansvarlig\"},{\"content\":\"Shipping\",\"val\":\"Branche / Industry\"}

How exactly do I go about this? My end result should be a pretty HTML table that's easily readable. I am very new to PHP and I don't have much experience with web dev, so the answers I've found else where aren't understandable for me. Here's my code that fetches the data:

```
$url = 'https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/private/json/Candidates/getRecords?authtoken=123456&scope=recruitapi&fromIndex=1&toIndex=1&selectColumns=Candidates(First%Name)&version=2';
                $request = new WP_Http;
                $result = $request->request($url, $data = array());
                $output = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                print_r($output);
```

The reason I use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is that there are æøå characters in the data.

Comment: use stripslashes() function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `json_decode()` function to actually decode the JSON string to an object or an associative array ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is the documentation). After that you just have to go through its elements and echo them in an appropriate html tags, e.g.:

```
$output = json_decode($result,1);

echo "<table>";
foreach ($output['Candidates']['row']['FL'] as $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $value['content'] . "</td><td>" . $value['val'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Getting some errors with this. json_decode only takes a string as a parameter, so it seems `$output` already is an array. The second error is that the argument for the foreach is invalid... which is probably caused by the first error.

Comment: Well are you sure that the result you get when requesting this url is a JSON actually? The `$output` can not just so be already an array. You can check that if you `var_dump()` the `$result` and `$output` variables. [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e16c9d21f46a8c69682d0453e55428f5e4831e8 ]. Also have a check if the JSON you get is a valid one, because the one you posted here has some missing curly braces.
P.s. This code I gave was only to give you an example.

Comment: I know it was an example, appreciate it. `$result` gives me something like `$output`, but the slashes aren't there. Meaning I don't use `json_encode` here. Does this mean it's not really JSON? I use JSON in the URL, and the API has that or XML as an option... but if it's not JSON then what is it? Because it doesn't look like XML.

Comment: JSON is only a type of data representation. It is actually transferred as a String. The example you gave here is a JSON which has actually some syntax errors - missing braces at the end. What I meant is if you're sure you're getting a response like this when requesting this url. That's why I told you to use the `var_dump()` function to see what's the type of the variables. The `$result` variable here should be a `String` and the `$output` should be an `Array` if you use the `json_decode($result, 1)` function.

Comment: The example I gave you is a snippet, the actual text printed out is way too long. I'm sorry if this caused some confusion. When printing `$result`, starts with this: `array(5) { ["headers"]=> array(12) { ["server"]=> string(3)`. I take it the data already is data? Or is this just a string saying there are arrays?

Comment: According to the docs [https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/ ] The wp_http::request function returns an array with 'headers', 'body', 'response', 'cookies', 'filename'. What you need here is the $response['body'] which should contain the JSON you need.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What kind of object should `$response` be? And array that includes the fields? I'm unable to find an example. I can imagine it's in the direction of the code example you already provided?